# Не могу понять в чем проблема. java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java

Вот мой код:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;'
import java.util.Iterator;'
import java.util.List;'

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> ourList = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = ourList.iterator();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            ourList.add(i + 1);
        }

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Выдает следующую ошибку при запуске:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:891)
    at Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ошибка говорит о том что вы модифицировали коллекцию параллельно с использованием итератора: в данном конкретном случае вы добавили элементы после создания итератора.

если перенести создание итератора после цикла с добавлением элементов то ошибки не будет.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло решить вопрос)

Answer (score 1):

В итераторе есть встроенная проверка на то, что коллекция не изменяется во время итерации.

Вы сперва создали итератор, он запомнил, что в коллекция пустая. Потом вы добавили в коллекцию элементы. Затем вы пытаетесь использовать итератор, но он обнаруживает, что коллекция изменилась, и выбрасывает исключение.

Вам нужно получать итератор неподсредственно перед использованием:

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = ourList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял, помогло)